# Get binding value of element in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

say I have this div in a `ng-repeat` clause:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" class="myDiv" ng-click="doStuff(item)">
    {{item.title}}
</div>
```

And it's based on this model:

```
$scope.list = [
    { 'title': 'Item 1', 'someData': 'lalala' },
    { 'title': 'Item 2', 'someData': '666' },
    { 'title': 'Item 3', 'someData': 'qwerty' }
  ];
```

Then I would end up getting 3 repeated divs.
Now I have an external script analyzing the page and I want to extract the data of the elements.
So for example if I select the first div `var div1 = $('div.myDiv:first')` I can get the attributes `ng-click` and `ng-repeat` from it. I can also use `angular.element(div1).data('$binding')` to get the binding `{{item.title}}`.
But what I really want is the individual item data of this particular div: i.e. I want to write a function `getItemData(element)` that will get `div1` and return `{ 'title': 'Item 1', 'someData': 'lalala' }`.

How can this be done?
Please note that I need a solution that would work **both with repeater binding and with regular binding**. I basically need to know the actual data that is bound to each element.

Comment: With an external script analyzing the page how can only get what you find in the page. So 'someDate' would not be available if not contained in the page, like in your example. Jquery should do the job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access element data object using `angular.element.scope` method:

```
var div1 = $('div.myDiv:first');
var dataItem = angular.element(div1).scope().item;
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/MzQRjdgqIpbe9LGrwMDZ?p=preview

Comment: I think the external script can not access the scope. Instead he has to parse the page with jquery and get the values.

Comment: @dec Yes, it can of course. You can access pretty much everything from outside: scope, services, injector, controllers, etc.

Comment: I think he thinks of another webpage or am I wrong?

Comment: @dec I think that by external script OP means something like user script or extension running on the same page, just outside of the app. *"for example if I select the first div var div1 = $('div.myDiv:first')"* which means that the script works on the same page.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Thanks!